# Why I am getting a Parsing error in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

i got a question.. i get a parsing error.. and i dont really know why. It seemes there is no "error" but it shows me. its the line in showPopover `this._timeId..`

```
        attachPopoverOnMouseover: function (targetControl, popover) {
        targetControl.addEventDelegate({
            onmouseover: this._showPopover.bind(this, targetControl, popover),
            onmouseout: this._clearPopover.bind(this, popover),
        }, this);
    },

    _showPopover: function (targetControl, popover) {
        this._timeId = setTimeout(() => popover.openBy(targetControl), 500);
    },

    _clearPopover: function (popover) {
        clearTimeout(this._timeId) || popover.close();
    },
```

[image]

The question is solved see the comments!

Comment: I have no idea what sapui5 is, but i bet the problem is arrow function which syntax result in error with your current linter settings. If im right, then just fix your settings

Comment: yeah you are right... i fixed it !! thanks ! its bc. sapui5 is on es5 instead of es6. I made it like es5 style now

Comment: @MoFug Please add the above comment as an answer below and accept it to let others know that this issue is resolved